# /etc/resolve.conf corrupted!

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, systemd-resolved

I've edited /etc/resolve.conf on my ubuntu 20.04 by mistake and it corrupted as below :

```
root@ubnt20srv-test-01:/etc# cat resolv.conf

 cat: resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

but the file exist:

```
root@ubnt20srv-test-01:/etc# ls -la | grep resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         39 Jul 31  2020 resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

and I get this error when I want to reedit it with vim :

```
"resolv.conf"
"resolv.conf" E166: Can't open linked file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

enter code here
```

I restarted VM but it didn't recreated. what should I do?

Comment: I have a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453982/ubuntu-22-04-1-nameservers-keep-getting-overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because the systemd-resolved.service was stopped. :)
I started the service and the file regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

root@techchamp:~# cd /etc/
root@techchamp:/etc# ls -la resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun  6 19:01 resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

## See above error solution is here :))

Now go to cd /run/systemd/ & create new folder name with **resolve** & open resolve folder

after that create nano file in this folder name with **resolv.conf**

Yeah that's done now you check again with nano /etc/resolv.conf it's open & working correctly...